# How to sign root file system and verify with FitImage

Tags: security, linux-kernel, yocto, imx6, rootfs

I am implementing secure boot for imx6ull.Barebox and Fitimage is signed and verified.

But how to sign root file system and verify with Fitimage .

I found some references like we can use dm-verity or dm-integrity kernel features.

But I am not sure how to include this in my rootfs and how to create a hash and signature for rootfs.

I am using yocto build set up. please let me know is there any reference example or steps how can I do this.

Do we need to use initramfs to achieve this ?